# I want the excel formula to get count of total line numbers which has multi line text in range?

Tags: excel

I want the excel formula to get count of total line numbers which has multi line text in range?

[image of hard coded excel sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y54a6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10),""))+1
```

And if you just want the total of the whole range, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B2:D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:D2,CHAR(10),"")))+COUNTA(B2:D2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Function CountLineBreaks(ByVal strSource As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim intResult As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
            Case 10, 13
                intResult = intResult + 1
        End Select
    Next
    CountLineBreaks = intResult + 1
End Function
```

Then use it in a cell as you would any other formula.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: =COUNTIF(A1:A10;"*[Alt+Enter]
*")